# Unsure about some parts of CS50 Lab 4: Volume

Tags: c, cs50

So in the lab we're first taking an input file, and copying its header into an output file. Then we copy the sample bits into the output file, after multiplying it by a factor that is determined by the user, which varies the amplitude of the output sound. I had a few questions regarding the code.

```
// Modifies the volume of an audio file

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Number of bytes in .wav header
const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check command-line arguments
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./volume input.wav output.wav factor\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open files and determine scaling factor
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    float factor = atof(argv[3]);

    // TODO: Copy header from input file to output file
    uint8_t header[HEADER_SIZE] = {0};

    fread(header, sizeof(uint8_t), 44, input);

    fwrite(header, sizeof(uint8_t), 44, output);


    // TODO: Read samples from input file and write updated data to output file
    int16_t sample;

    while(fread(&sample, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input) == 1)
    {
        sample = sample*factor;
        fwrite(&sample, sizeof(int16_t), 1, output);
    }

    // Close files
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);


}
```

1. Can i use fputc() instead of fwrite() to copy the header over to the output file?

```
fwrite(header, sizeof(uint8_t), 44, output);
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < HEADER_SIZE; i++) {  fputc(header[i], output);  }
```

2. When we copy the samples over to the output file, is the file pointer for the output already at the 44th position? Cuz it finished writing the first 44 bytes for the header already?

3. Don't we only use the while syntax like that when the statement returns true or false? Doesn't fread() return 1 here cuz we are copying 1 bit at a time and 0 if we reach the end of the file?

Comment: If you want to read and write binary file, then please open them in binary mode. Like e.g. `"rb"` and `"wb"`.

Comment: "Can i use fputc()" You can, but there's no reason for doing that. "is the file pointer for the output already at the 44th position?" Yes it is, why is that a problem or concern? "Don't we only use the while syntax like that when the statement returns true or false?" First, any integer can be used as a condition, 0 being false and anything else playing the role of true. Second, this particular `while` uses the result of `==`, not the result of `fwrite`.

Comment: In addition, you should check return value of *every* call to a function that returns a status. `fread(header, sizeof(uint8_t), 44, input);` There are several things that can go wrong here. A file can be shorter that 44 bytes or an I/O error could occur. Check that it returns 44. Same about `fwrite`. You have adequate error checking in several places, but it should be everywhere. Oh and use `HEADER_SIZE` throughout, rather than the literal `44`.

Comment: So you are saying that i should apply the same while loop for the other fread and fwrite statements as well to avoid errors? I'll keep that in mind. Also, regarding my 2nd question, do all the file functions like fread, fwrite etc. update the file pointer's location?

Comment: No, you should use `if` logic similar to that used with `fopen`.